# Push notifications targeted to "family" of apps

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have a group of applications that share the same bundle prefix.  They are targets in the same project.
We wish to send push notifications that pertain to the whole group applications, so that the user doesn't get the same notification
multiple times, one for each app of the group.  Is there some official way to send such push notifications?

Comment: Is the device token the same in your case between a device and all of your apps? Or is it generating a unique device token for each app? For instance if I have an iPhone with 5 of your apps, will it give you 5 different device tokens or just 1

Comment: If you have 5 of those apps, they will generate 5 different device tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not official way to handle your case. As far as Apple is concerned, there is no relation between the apps in your "family". You'll have to implement this relation yourself.

Here's a possible way to do it :

1. Each application will have a separate push certificate (there's no other way).
2. Each application that registers to APNS will send a device token to your server, along with an identifier of the app that sends the token.
3. Your server must associate (in its DB) the device token with the app identifier.
4. When you send a push notification to a device token, you must use the correct certificate (based on the app identifier), in order to send it to the app associated with that token.
5. If the same device has more than one of your apps installed, it's up to your server to decide whether to push a notification to one of them or to all of them. In order to be able to push to just one of them, when you send the device token to the server, you must send an additional identifier that identifies the device (I would generate my own random identifier and store it locally on the device, where other apps can find and reuse it if it already exists). Multiple applications on the same device would use the same device identifier, even if they have different device tokens (which is possible in iOS7 and later versions). When your server sends a push notification, it will send only one notification per each device identifier (even if there are multiple device tokens associated with it).

Comment: I think you're right, that's the way to go about it. Thanks very much for the complete and detailed answer.